# How to get data from firebase?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to do a simple app to learn how to acess firebase and manipulate data inside it. I want to get an array of users that exists in my firebase.
I did everything but when I call the screen it doesn't show, it keeps in the screen that I was, and my console is not showing any thing. Can anyone help me?

Here's my users.module

```js
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('hsAdmin.users', [
            'ionic',
            'hsAdmin.common'
        ])
        .config(function($stateProvider) {
        
        $stateProvider
            .state('app.users', {
                url: '/users',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/users/users.html',
                        controller: 'UsersCtrl as vm'
                    }
                },
                resolve:{
                    Users: function(UsersService) {
                        return UsersService.GetUsers().then(function(users){
                            return users;
                        }).catch(function(error){
                             console.log('Error when get users: ' + error);
                        })
                    }

                }
            });
        })  
})();
```

Here's my users.controller

```js
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('hsAdmin.users')
        .controller('UsersCtrl', UsersCtrl);

    UsersCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state','Users'];

    function UsersCtrl($scope, $state,Users){
        var vm = angular.extend(this, {
    Users:Users,
    ChangeState:ChangeState
        });

        function ChangeState(state){
            $state.go(state);
        }

    }    
})();
```

Here's my users.service

```js
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('hsAdmin.users')
        .factory('UsersService', UsersService);

    UsersService.$inject = ['fb', '$firebaseArray', '$firebaseObject','$q','$rootScope'];

    function UsersService(fb, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject,$q,$rootScope){
        var service = {
            GetUsers:GetUsers
        };
        return service;


        function GetUsers(){
            var query = fb.child('/users');
            return $firebaseArray(query).$loaded();
        }

        function GetUserById(id){
            var query = fb.child('/users/' + id);
            return $firebaseObject(query).$loaded();
        }
    }
})();
```

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: Try to use angularfire

https://github.com/firebase/angularfire

Comment: I already included it in my project, but nothing happens when i call the screen

Comment: $loaded() is a promise. Try use this way:

$loaded().then(function(){

...

});

Comment: still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what was going on. I made 2 mistakes, first of all, I was not loged in on firebase ( no authentication method), and to get data from firebase is necessary to be loged. The second mistake is that I injected '$scope" in  my service. I did the login, took the $scope of and everything worked fine